# Sql Data to Excel File with Excel connection in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I want to know that is there a chance to save Sql data to excel file without using Excel destination task and without using Excel connection in Script task.
If any answer please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Yes you could use `ScriptTask` and do the complete stuff by using `C#`, but why do you want to perform something for which already tools are present.

Comment: Or export to flat file CSV (comma separated values) and it will open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to import SQL data to Excel sheet without Excel task and excel connection of ADO.net or any SSIS Excel connections. I did it in a script task. I used documentformat.openxml package. I installed openxml package in NuGet manager. Then It didn't work showing some errors. When I opened the code reference was sowing some error. Then, I changed the reference path of the package manually and tried. It worked. Hope it would help someone.
Thank You,

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataToExcel
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(@"E:\Work\One.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {

                string connString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True;";//Windows authentication
                
                SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Test", sqlConn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                sqlConn.Close();
                List<string> header = new List<string>();
                int count = dt.Rows.Count;
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    header.Add(column.ColumnName);
                }

                //Here is the code for Excel saving.
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new SheetData();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1" };

                sheets.Append(sheet);

                Row headerRow = new Row();

                foreach (var item in header)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(item);
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (DataRow dsrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Row newRow = new Row();
                    foreach (String col in header)
                    {
                        Cell cell = new Cell();
                        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }

                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }

        }
    }
}
```